# PHP session / document folder with PDF

Tags: php

I have created a web applicaiton/site where people are required to log and are able to access some files to view (PDFs).

My issue is I as I am storing these files on the server, in a documentation folder people can access the files directly without having to log in (if they know the random url for example www.example.com/documentation/example1.pdf).

I am using sessions to control if they are logged in or not, but how can i prevent direct access to people just hotlinking the direct link if they are not logged in or have an open session?

If i set the permissons via filezilla, it restricts all access regardless if they are logged in or not.

Can anyone provide advice on a solution I could take for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forbid public access to the folder. Just create a .htaccess file in folder and put this in it:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From All
```

Next make a script that checks if user is logged in and serves the file.

It would look something like this:

```
...
if (userLoggedIn()) {
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ' . $_GET['file']);
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');
   readfile($path . $_GET['file']);
}
...
```

In this case your user needs to make a request like *www.example.com/download.php?file=example1.pdf* instead of *www.example.com/documentation/example1.pdf*

Comment: Also you can place the files in a non public folder

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit please? How do i set the permission for a folder so it only allows the server to see the file.
Where would the script be located, and is userLoggedIn related to the session?

Comment: @user2661760 Sorry, I don't know if its possible to do it with permissions. But it can be done with .htaccess file. Check my answer again I have updated it.